# Move-SPUser - only changing upa but not mysite url with new id

Tags: 2010, powershell, user-profile, user-profile-service, my-site

SharePoint 2010: `Move-SPUser` works however in SP 2010 it does not change the mysite url to reflect user's new id. for example, mysite.fu.bar/sites/oldid so it should be mysite.fu.bar/sites/newid. The UPA is updated with the new id. Any reason for this? I waited few hours so UPA can update the mysite url and now it's 14 hours after I ran the command. Please suggest something.

```
$currUser = Get-SPUser -Identity $CurrentNetworkLogin -Web $web
Move-SPUser -Identity $currUser -NewAlias $FutureNetworkLogin -IgnoreSid -Confirm:$false
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sites will be migrated when you change the Site Naming Format, but last I looked, not the user's username [using `Move-SPUser`].

Comment: But Trevor why this setting is working in SP 2013 and not 2010.